# Generate a filtered subset of repeated permutations of an array of objects (with given length k)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, permutation

I'm new to Ruby. I need to generate all combinations of objects based on a length.

For example, `array = [obj1, obj2, obj3]`, `length = 2`, then combinations are:

```
[
  [obj1, obj1],
  [obj1, obj2],
  [obj1, obj3],
  # ...
  [obj3, obj3]
]
```

I know I can use `repeated_permutation` method for this problem, but I need also to be able to **filter** some permutations. For example, to filter out permutations where 2 identical objects are one after another, i.e. like this `[obj1, obj1]`.

Comment: `{ obj1, obj2, obj3 }` is not a valid object in Ruby

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, I know, I just used math notation for sets.

Comment: ackacky, there are two problems with the definition of `set`. @Andrey mentioned one. The second is that `obj1` (and the others) are either variables with unknown values or unspecified methods. For the purpose of the question you should make them literals, strings or symbols. You need to write, say, `require 'set'; set = [:obj1, :obj2, :obj3].to_set #=> #<Set: {:obj1, :obj2, :obj3}>` (or `Set.new [:obj1, :obj2, :obj3]`). You need to edit to fix that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I am sorry if question isn't clear, but permutation generation problem itself is described not as ruby problem. It's just abstract description of problem.

Comment: Please do not alter the question once comments or answers have been posted, but if you do, note that you have done so in your edit. Silent changes can render comments and answers incorrect or nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an arbitrary input array:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

If you *only* wish to generate the unique permutations, then you can simply do:

```
a.uniq.permutation(2)
```

(`uniq` is not needed, if you know the initial array contains unique elements!)

However, as a more general solution, you must do:

```
a.repeated_permutation(2).reject { |permutation| ** FILTER RULE GOES HERE ** }
```

So for example, if you wish to filter all results which do not have **two consecutive repeated values**, then you can do:

```
a.repeated_permutation(2).reject do |permutation|
  permutation.each_cons(2).any? {|x, y| x == y}
end
```

Taking this to the extreme, here is a generalised method:

```
def filtered_permutations(array, length)
  array.repeated_permutation(length).reject{|permutation| yield(permutation)}
end

# Or, if you prefer:

def filtered_permutations(array, length, &block)
  array.repeated_permutation(length).reject(&block)
end

# Usage:

a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]

filtered_permutations(a, 2) {|permutation| permutation.each_cons(2).any? {|x, y| x == y} }

# Or, if you prefer:
filtered_permutations(a, 2) {|permutation| permutation.each_cons(2).any? {|consecutive| consecutive.uniq.one?} }
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is to remove any pairs that are the same obj, you can simply use the [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) method.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.permutation(2).to_a

#=>  [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a block where you perform your "filtering". So to remove those with identical elements you'd go with:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.repeated_permutation(2).reject { |permutation| permutation.uniq.one? }
#=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Comment: so if `length=3`,`[1, 2, 1]` should be valid, but `permutation.uniq.one?` will return false

Comment: it should return false, the `reject` method removes any element where the block returns true. So `[1,2,1]` will not be rejected.

Comment: @ackacky.bashmachckin it will return `false`, because you asked to reject if all the same

Comment: @davidhu2000, yes, you're right. the problem is that `[1, 1, 2]` `[1, 2, 2]` will not be rejected too.

Comment: Are those supposed to be rejected? I thought you will only reject `[1,1,1]`?

Comment: This is the correct answer for a **generic** filter method. However, for the special case of only filtering the "repeated values", you should just use `Array#permutation` - and then there's no need for any `Array#reject` stuff.

Comment: @TomLord, no in this special case I need to filter permutations where two equals objects are one after another. For example, if `set = {'a', 'b', 'c'}` and `length=3` then we need to filter out `"aab", "abb", "bba", ...` and not to filter out `"aba"`

Comment: @ackacky.bashmachckin so `"aha"` does not have consecutive letters, why to filter it?

Comment: You did not make this at all clear in your question. Based on this **new** information, I can provide an answer below - but please try to explain the requirements better in future.